# Possible CSS error on my <p:fileUpload>

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

I'm using: Tomcat 7, JSF 2.2, Primefaces 4.0 on my project.

I'm having some issues with my `<p:fileUpload>` component. It's firing the `mouseOver` event on the "Choose File" button when I move the mouse on it's left side. And if a click, the "Choose File" action is fired.

This is my page
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHW1X.png

If I put the mouse inside the red rectangle, the `mouseOver` event is fired.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEAQ6.png

I tried this CSS:

```
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar .ui-fileupload-choose input {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

It fixes the `mouseOver` problem. But when I click the "Choose File" button, the action doens't fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from Diego's answer I added this css rule:

```
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

That solved the problem without having to add anything but css.

Answer (score 1):

It have a width?
Try `float` or wrap with a div and set `overflow: hidden`.

Can we see the css style ?

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for your answer. The `overflow: hidden`, helped me, as a workaround. Now, the `mouseOver` event occours only inside the `p:fileUpload`, on the bottom and left side. It's not a full fix, but it's fine for me. I will consider your answer as the correct one. Thanks a lot! I inspected the element on Chrome (using the p:fileUpload wrapped on a div). Look at it: http://i.imgur.com/9OziXBm.png

Comment: Man, the best solution:

Set a `display:hidden` to `<input type="file">`;

Change the `<span class="ui-button-text ui-c">` to `<label for="formUpload:upload_input" class="ui-button-text ui-c">`

Comment: Hi Diego. Thanks for your help. But I think I cant change it as you say. The components on the photo comes from the `<p:fileUpload>` in my .xhtml file. I dont explicit write all of them, just the `<p:fileUpload>`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think CSS has to do with firing the action, its probably on your jquery or whatever action codes you have for "Choose File".

Comment: Well, when I put that CSS, it fixes the mouseOver problem. But the click action is not fired when the button is pressed.